# Create instance with specified Culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

Before I create instance, I set culture for current thread for format money, datetime...

```
// Set culture info for thread
var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureInfoName);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

object instance = assemblyDs.CreateInstance(dataSet.ClassTypeName, true, BindingFlags.Default, null, classInstanceParameters, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, null);
```

I get null for instance, but when I pass null instead of Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, instance is created successfully.

My question: is it culture is have problem? and why I pass null, it get CultureInfo and created succesfully, but when I pass Culture which I set, it couldn't be?

Comment: what is your cultureInfoName ?

Comment: My culture name is en-US. I figured out my setting in Date & Time effects on it. I dont know why, I tested on my co-worker, it's normal. After that, I test on my pc, it's broken, then I reset setting in Date & Time, and the problem is gone.